# What is the need for the Higgs mechanism and electroweak unification?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

The Higgs mechanism allows massless fields to acquire mass through their coupling to a scalar field. But if the masses cannot be predicted because the couplings have to be fixed, what really is the utility of the Higgs mechanism? Instead of saying "Here are *a priori* couplings; the Higgs mechanism generates mass.", I could just as well say "Here are *a priori* masses. Period.".

I understand that the Higgs mechanism is crucial to electroweak unification, but I have the same question there. Why does electromagnetism and the weak force have to be unified? Even if the couplings of the photon, Z and W bosons became related on unification, this is still at the cost of introducing new parameters - so it's not really clear to me that something has been explained or tidied up.

Do either the Higgs mechanism or electroweak unification tell us something new? Do either make any predictions that don't come at the cost of extra parameters? (I'm not really challenging anything here; I'm sure the answer to both questions is 'yes' - I just want to fill the gaps in my understanding as I study the Standard Model)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dbrane, aside from "beauty", the electroweak unification is actually needed for a finite theory of weak interactions. The need for all the fields found in the electroweak theory may be explained step by step, requiring the "tree unitarity".

This is explained e.g. in this book by Jiří Hořejší:

> [http://www.amazon.com/dp/9810218575/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810218575)
>   **Google books:**
>  http://books.google.com/books?id=MnNaGd7OtlIC&printsec=frontcover&hl=cs#v=onepage&q&f=false

The sketch of the algorithm is as follows:

Beta-decay changes the neutron to a proton, electron, and an antineutrino; or a down-quark to an up-quark, electron, and an anti-neutrino. This requires a direct four-fermion interaction, originally sketched by Fermi in the 1930s, and improved - including the right vector indices and gamma matrices - by Gell-Mann and Feynman in the 1960s.

However, this 4-fermion interaction is immediately in trouble. It's non-renormalizable. You may see the problem by noticing that the tree-level probability instantly exceeds 100% when the energies of the four interacting fermions go above hundreds of GeV or so.

The only way to fix it is to regulate the theory at higher energies, and the only consistent way to regulate a contact interaction is to explain it as an exchange of another particle. The only right particle that can be exchanged to match basic experimental tests is a vector boson. Well, they could also exchange a massive scalar but that's not what Nature chose for the weak interactions.

So there has to be a massive gauge boson, the W boson.

One finds out inconsistency in other processes, and has to include the Z-bosons as well. One also has to add the partner quarks and leptons - to complete the doublets - otherwise there are problems with other processes (probabilities of interactions, calculated at the tree level, exceed 100 percent). It goes on and on.

At the end, one studies the scattering of two longitudinally polarized W-bosons at high energies, and again, it surpasses 100 percent. The only way to subtract the unwanted term is to add new diagrams where the W-bosons exchange a Higgs boson. That's how one completes the Standard Model, including the Higgs sector. Of course, the final result is physically equivalent to one that assumes the "beautiful" electroweak gauge symmetry to start with.

It's a matter of taste which approach is more fundamental and more logical. But it's certainly true that the form of the Standard Model isn't justified just by aesthetic criteria; it can be justified by the need for it to be consistent, too.

By the way, 3 generations of quarks are needed for CP-violation - if this were needed. There's not much other explanation why there are 3 generations. However, the form of the generations is tightly constrained, too - by anomalies. For example, a Standard Model with quarks and no leptons, or vice versa, would also be inconsistent (it would suffer from gauge anomalies).

Comment: Nice outline, Lubosh! I like you mentioned some difficulties.

Comment: Now *that* is the kind of answer I was looking for :) I'm all for beauty and elegance too, but in the end I would only let an inconsistency like non-unitarity or anomalies make me add things to my theory. Thanks for the great answer again Lubos - I'll see if I can find a copy of the book you referred to.

Comment: Thanks, @dbrane, and good luck in finding it for free (there are 3 copies left at amazon). The author was my QFT instructor in Prague.  @Vladimir, right, there are problems, but the goal - and a successful one - of the procedure is to solve the difficulties. And indeed, they're solved at the end.

Comment: Great, I just discovered that there *are* physics books that you can't find in *any* of the Cambridge libraries. :/

Comment: @Vladimir, why do you name Lubos as Lubosh? He doesn't name himself that way and gives the impression of you lacking a respectful, fair attitude towards people.

Comment: @John, it's plausible that Vladimír is trying to deform my name for malicious reasons - but I have actually loved to spell my name as Lubosh, at least before I got to the U.S. haha (but Vladimír probably doesn't know that I did so). Also, I spell it Lubosch when I communicate with Germans - at least at some moments haha. By the way, I spelled his name "Vladimír" because it's the right Czech way to spell it. I think that Eastern Slavic nations' names should be transcribed to Western languages via their form in the civilized Western Slavic languages such as Czech.

Comment: To John McVirgo: I spell it so because I think it is pronounced so. Although Lubosh never voted up for my posts, I respect and love him. I was not sure about spelling and asked him directly once. He did not reply and never complained about my way of spelling. If I really distort your name, Lubosh, tell me, I will change it for what you want.

Comment: @vladimir, apologies for misinterpreting you then.

Comment: It's because "Lubosh" is easier to type than "Luboš", at least on my computer. I'm lazy so I just call him "Dr. Motl".

Comment: i like this explanation a lot, very motivational, +1

Answer (score 0):

Electroweak unification means that there is a symmetry between electromagnetic and weak interactions -- you can use them interchangeably. In reality this is not the case -- $W$ and $Z$ bosons have mass, while photon haven't.

Higgs mechanism provides a way for a *spontaneous symmetry breaking* between those interactions: Lagrangian of standard model is electroweak symmetric, while the vacuum is not due to non-zero vacuum expectation value for the Higgs field.

The same applies for fermions -- you cannot introduce mass terms for quarks and leptons in the Lagrangian, while preserving the electroweak symmetry. But it is possible to introduce electroweak symmetric Yukawa terms, coupling Higgs field to the fermions.

Edit:
I don't think that Higgs mechanism can "tell us something new". It is just a simplest way to ensure spontaneous symmetry breaking. While electroweak unification means that those interactions are gauge interactions and establishes the gauge symmetry itself. The classification of fermions into three generations is also done from the "electroweak point of view".

Of course you can argue that this systematization or classification is not "something new". But from such a point of view one can criticise almost every theoretical construction that attempts to predict results of future experiments.

Comment: Thanks, but you haven't answered my question, you've just made it a bit more explicit. Introducing mass terms breaks electroweak symmetry. So instead, we impose electroweak symmetry on a massless theory and use the Higgs mechanism to generate back the masses. My question is, why not assume there never was an electroweak symmetry to start with, and all along work with a massive theory without any symmetry breaking? That's one less scalar field and one less particle to look for.

Comment: Of course, it's great that this leads to the *prediction* of a new particle. But I can't, at the moment, see why Nature would want to burden itself with an additional scalar field and associated particle when it could do everything as an SSB-less theory with the same number of free parameters.

Comment: Very good reasoning! I support it with two my hands!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that recognizing that  the data have an SU2xU1 symmetry one has a number of parameters and one may say that problem number one has been reduced to problem number two which has the same number of unknowns.

Let me give the often quoted example of the epicycles in the geocentric system and the ellipses in the heliocentric one. The number of parameters are the same, and if you go to a planetarium program and go to the geocentric frame, the epicycles will appear in all their glory. Nevertheless there is nobody now who would ask, "what is the use of ordering the data in the heliocentric system".

Asking "why should electromagnetism be unified with weak theory" is a bit like asking "why have a heliocentric system".The answer is that in both cases, the data fall into an ordered form effortlessly. And then we were led to higher symmetries (SU3xSU2xU1) and more inclusive theories.

I should have added that the clarity introduced by  symmetries/order once manifested lead to calculable theories which can describe the data and make predictions for new observations. The Higgs is one such prediction coming out from the theories describing the quark model symmetries. If it is not found, a rethink will be in order, (though there are papers which claim that a Higgs mechanism can be a composite manifestation, not necessarily one particle).

Comment: "effortlessly"? How much fog they supply to hide failures of this approach!

Comment: @Anna: No, it's not the same because requiring unification *introduces a new physical particle*. It's not at all like looking at things from a more natural frame of reference (as in heliocen. vs. geocen.) because there the two descriptions are equally valid in that they don't differ in predictions - but differ in how they fit in naturally with known theories of celestial mechanics.

Comment: @dbrane Well, the heliocentric system introduces a force, that was not present in the geocentric view of the world, no?

Comment: But the geocentric view involves forces too of course - only they are much more complicated to calculate because of the "unnatural" choice of coordinates. And again, in the end, the predictions are the same.

Comment: To Anna: I disagree with your analogy with celestial mechanics. And you speak of introducing a "new physical particle" as a human intellect achievement whereas it is a fix of worthless (massless) theory. I can remind you bare particles, virtual particles, ghosts - all invented to stay in this failed approach. I would love to learn how physical electron looks like. Nobody can describe it yet.

Comment: @dbrane, for many centuries, there were no forces, just observations ordered into the celestial sphere and epicycle problem. In the same way, you could probably write up everything without acknowledging the existing symmetries and it would be a long project to get at the same results that fall into place when the symmetries are considered.

Comment: @Vladimir I would suggest that you contemplate a bit the figures :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_%28physics%29 . Those come from hard data and display a great symmetry and led to the su3xsu2xu1 organization that brought us the quarks and leptons in one model.

Comment: @Anna: Ok, I see now that you are comparing pre-Newtonian ignorance of forces to us not acknowledging the existence of electroweak symmetry. But my whole point is that the world as far as we know it from experiment, *does not* respect electroweak symmetry - you'd say it's broken but that requires more "Occam" baggage in the form of the Higgs particle. Forces weren't introduced and then wiped off with another concept like how electroweak symmetry is introduced and then wiped off with the Higgs mechanism.

Comment: To Anna: I know that. The problem is that nobody can explain what quarks are, as well as the other particles. Are they bare, dressed, or you do not care?

Comment: @Anna: Also, the Eightfold Way has to do with just SU(3) symmetry (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not denying the existence or usefulness of SU(3) (exact colour or approximate flavour), SU(2) or U(1) independently. I'm asking why cross SU(2) and U(1)? :)

Comment: @dbrane you should also look at the eightfold way ordering of particles and resonances http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_%28physics%29 . The world as we know it respects electro weak symmetry approximately for the masses, hence the need of breaking the symmetry, not because of the quantum numbers, but because the masses in a multiplet are not the same. In the heliocentric example maybe the ellipses might be deformed :) ( which they are when everything is taken to account). This does not detract from the usefulness of the symmetries apparent in the heliocentric system.

Comment: @Anna: I don't really see how this is relevant since approx. SU(3) flavor symmetry isn't really a consequence of any fundamental hypothesised SSB, as far as I know. Hmmm, that actually makes me want to ask another question - why is there an approx. SU(3) flavor symmetry at all? :/

Comment: @dbrane The SU3 of the eightfold way is not the SU3 of SU3XSU2XU1. It led people to think about symmetry groups and Lie algebras.

Comment: @Anna: I know, I'm aware of the distinction between exact colour SU(3) which appears in SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) and approx. flavour SU(3)

Comment: @dbrane have a look at this analysis http://pdg.lbl.gov/2010/reviews/rpp2010-rev-quark-model.pdf . It shows the same plots in a quark model

Comment: Sorry, wrong link http://pdg.lbl.gov/2010/reviews/rpp2010-rev-quark-model.pdf

Comment: @Vladimir The quark model organizes the data successfully, that is its justification. In the link above the Omega- was predicted before it was found, just from the symmetries.

Comment: Yes, I know. I speak of theoretical constructions. Some of them, despite introduced symmetries, are hard to deal with practically. For example, quarks are good for "organizing data" but when we ask about quark itself, it turns out the quark is nondetachable, always tightly bound thing, difficult to separate as a single "particle".

Answer (score -5):

In a phenomenological approach one introduces masses without problem.

It is in the "local gauge invariance" approaches where one needs **a fix** because the gauge approach does not give masses, unfortunately. Technically it is is implemented as "coupling" to Higgs in some way.

I never considered the "local gauge invariance principle" as reasonable or physical. It is one of many blind ways to "construct" interacting theories; it does not guarantee anything physical and does not save us from infinities in calculations. It's been done by analogy with QED which itself has problems. **This way needs fixes.**

I would say the Higgs is a price for choosing a "mathematical" rather than physical approach to constructing theories. It is a wrong guess, in my opinion. There are  more physical ideas on this subject but they remain unknown and thus unexploited.

Comment: what is this "phenomenological approach" you refer to?

Comment: Do you remember the Schroedinger equation with $m_e$ or Dirac equation with $m_e$? Something like this, if you like.